# After submitting EditForm, component does not rerender

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

Good day!

I use Blazor component for rendering and updating non-sql database information. I expected the re-rendering of the component after submission, but, even after calling `this.StateHasChanged();`, I have to manually refresh the page. My code does not have errors or warning messages.

After reading the official Blazor and ASP.net documentation, lots of tutorials and answers on stackoverflow, I still can not figure why the component is not refreshing.

I also manually tried to refresh the component's content using a control variable and `if()` statements.

Thank you!

```
@page "/admin/selectcategory"

<h5>SelectCategory</h5>

@{
    int count = categoryList.Count;
    if (count != 0)
    {
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush mt-3 mb-5">
            @foreach (var rec in categoryList)
            {
                <a href="Category/@rec.ID" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pl-0 py-4">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <h5 class="mb-1 mt-2">@rec.Name</h5>
                        <small>500 anunturi</small>
                    </div>
                    <p class="mt-1">@rec.Description</p>
                    <small class="text-muted">Lorem, Ipsum, Dolor sit, Amet...</small>
                </a>
            }
        </div>
    }
    <h3 class="panel-title my-2">Add Category</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <EditForm Model="@newCategory" OnValidSubmit="AddCategory"
              class="my-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="newCategory.Name"
                   class="form-control py-3 px-3 my-2"
                   id="new-category-name"
                   placeholder="Category Name" />
        <InputTextArea @bind-Value="newCategory.Description"
                       class="form-control py-3 px-3 my-2"
                       id="new-category-description"
                       placeholder="Description" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light py-2 px-3 my-2">Create Category</button>
    </EditForm>
}

@code{
    private List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();
    private Category newCategory = new Category();
    private Category cat = new Category();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() => categoryList = await Task.Run(() => cat.Read("CategoryList"));

    private async Task AddCategory()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => newCategory.Create("CategoryList"));
        newCategory = new Category();
        this.StateHasChanged();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not adding the item to the list after create. Or you should call the same code you have in OnInitializedAsync() again. Which is why it is showing on refresh.

Comment: Thank You for quickly answering my question. Adding Appending the new object to the list fixed it. :)